# How to pause page transitions until modal is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that I show with:

```
// display authentication
if (self.current === 0){
    this.authenticated  = false;
    $('#login-modal').modal();
}
```

I have listeners for things associated with this modal:

```
    $("#login-modal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
            if( !this.authenticated )
                //do stuff, cancel, etc.
    });

    $("#login-modal").on('keydown', function( ev ) {
        var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;
        // enter
        if( keyCode === 13 ) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $('#aws-submit').click();
        }
    } );

    // modal Login button
    $('#aws-submit').click(function( ev ) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var awsu = $('#awsu').val();
        var awsp = $('#awsp').val();

        if( awsu && awsp ) {
            $('#login-modal').submit();
            $('#login-modal').modal('hide');
        }

        if( !awsu ) {
            $('#awsu').addClass('missing-input');
        } else {
            $('#awsu').removeClass('missing-input');
        }

        if( !awsp ) {
            $('#awsp').addClass('missing-input');
        } else {
            $('#awsp').removeClass('missing-input');
        }
    });
```

But what I've noticed is my page continues it's transition in the background while waiting for the modal input (i.e., it goes to the next question in my list of questions). This happens because after the `$('#login-modal').modal()` is a call to `self._nextQuestion();` which triggers the transition.

Is there a way I can pause execution somehow until the modal is hidden/dismissed/etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you move your call to `self._nextQuestion();` into your click handler for `#aws-submit` or your `hide.bs.modal` handler, then the page shouldn't transition until the user is done with the modal and submits it.

Comment: The issue is that this is common logic for the form, so I need the `self._nextQuestion()` to be here for when `self.current != 0`